# Problem with caption numbering custom float after renewing section command

Tags: sectioning, floats, numbering

How can I avoid this extra dot in caption that appears without removing     `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{float} 

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}

\floatstyle{plain}
\newfloat{graphic}{thp}{lop}[section] 
\floatname{graphic}{Grafikon}

\begin{document}

\begin{graphic}
\caption{some fancy \texttt{caption} }
\label{fig:flowchart}
\end{graphic}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With a KOMA-class, you could use `numbers=enddot` as global option, giving you the desired dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to add the period to `\thesection`, but rather to modify how the section titles are typeset, adding a period after the number; unfortunately there's no “official” user interface for this, but it's not difficult either.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{float}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
\makeatother

\floatstyle{plain}
\newfloat{graphic}{thp}{lop}[section]
\floatname{graphic}{Grafikon}

\begin{document}
\section{Grafikon}
\begin{graphic}
\caption{some fancy \texttt{caption}}
\label{fig:flowchart}
\end{graphic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ty, I forgot to mention one more thing. Which is that my current default figures have one more dot after number and before colon. Like this: Figure 1.1.: fancy caption

Comment: @msvalina Have you redefined also `\thefigure`?

Comment: Yes I redefined it in same way: \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}.}

Comment: @msvalina Don't.

Comment: Yeah but that is desired style, but I don't know how to get that extra dot on graphic float?

Comment: @msvalina Please, update your question, specifying clearly what you need.